# .png images load great - .jpg images are blurry on website

Tags: images, jpeg, png

I've searched around and found lots of information about blurry images and I've implemented some of the fixes I found and it worked on about 50% of them.

I'm posting Android apps and iOS apps - all the Android app posts have crystal clear images and the Apple app posts are all blurry. From what I can tell the Android images are all .png and the Apple images are .jpg.

With 50,000 images I'm just not sure how to handle this…I thought of bulk converting to .png but then all the paths change from ending in .jpg to .png.

I've shut off the "opacity" function in the theme and I've tried with both the retina capability enabled and disabled, also searched the functions.php for any image compression taking place - couldn't find any.

The images are all 300x300 and being displayed at 270x270, near as I can tell.

The site is http://healthitlink.com if anyone has a minute to check it all out.

Thank you!
Robert

Comment: You are stretching the JPEG images from 100x100 to 270x270, so that's not good for quality whereas the PNS are sized at 270x270, so their not being stretched.

Comment: Hi HeavyD - nope, no re-encoding that I know of. The images are downloaded, during the post creation, directly from Apple and/or Google Play. They are all created in the same manner - the iOS and Android posts that is - so I don't think there is anything specifically happening to the iOS images that I know of…but they appear blurry. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, see my edit.

Comment: Ah…okay…thank you! So let me ask you this ;) Is there a way to make the  jpg images display at 100x100 and leave the settings for png images as they are?

Comment: That is going to be specific to the platform you're using to host your website.

Comment: Okay, thanks Heavy! I think I'll have to figure out something in the CSS of the theme because on a different theme it displays ALL the images as 100x100 so there was no problem - until I switched themes ;)

Comment: @heavyd Please post a real answer below, with a little more detail. (See deleted post below)